# Best practices to avoid "Too many connections" error

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I recently noticed several **"Too many connections"** errors on my site. I know the reasons and ways to "solve" this problem but I have to admit that I don't know the best practices to avoid this problem or how to improve my code.

I will post a theoretical code (Please assume that everything is working), and I ask you guys to help me with some questions and how to improve this code. That way I can fix my other codes.

**connection.php**

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DATABASE;charset=utf8','USER', 'PASSWORD');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

**my_page.php**

```
include("connection.php");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE condition = :condition");
$stmt->bindParam(':condition', $condition, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->rowCount();


function getName($id){
global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE condition = :condition");
    $stmt->bindParam(':condition', $condition, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->rowCount();
}

function getCompany($id){
global $conn;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tableC WHERE condition = :condition");
    $stmt->bindParam(':condition', $condition, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

**MY QUESTIONS ARE:**

1) How many database connections were opened in the code above?

2) Each time a query is made, using ($stmt = $conn->prepare), a new connection is opened?

3) There is a way to optimize the code above, assuming that **INNER JOIN** or any other query optimization is not possible? I mean, there are 3 tables (Not related) and I need to query information from them without opening new connections.

Comment: How dynamic does your code need to be? Have you consider adding a level of caching, so you do not have to call your database as much.

Comment: Using a connection pool to limit your connection

Comment: Just after you establish a connection to the database in connection.php add the line echo 'A connection has been established to the database'; Does that then appear multiple times?

Comment: @darol100 Unfortunately the code need to be dynamic, I've tried to store as much info on arrays but I think it looked more like a work around than the right way

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Just one

Comment: Is the server a dedicated server or a shared server?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix It's a Shared Server. I know that shared server have limited connections but I think that I could improve my code to work better

Comment: What about $stmt->close()?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, and as much as I have read, we should use `$stmt->closeCursor()`, and `$pdo = null`. Hope to see a PDO/MySQL warrior post a proper answer here soon..

Comment: @AymDev Did you notice some improvements using `$stmt->closeCursor()` and `$pdo = null`? I really hope someone could answer the proper way to do it too...

Comment: @suicidebilly I haven't tried yet (busy on something else), I bookmark your question to give you an answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your specific questions

1) One connection per call of  "my_page.php" is open.

2) A new connection is opened on every call of "my_page.php".

3) There is scope of optimising your code. You should create a
   connection class and use singleton pattern to get DB connection
   whenever required.